# Possibly differing definitions of local path-connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces, path-connected, locally-connected

In C.C.Pugh's book "Real Mathematical Analysis" a metric space $X$ is said to be locally path-connected if for each $p\in X$ and (open) neighborhood $U$ containing $p$ there is a path-connected (open) subneighborhood $V$ of $p$.

However, Wikipedia states that a topological space $X$ (for our purposes, let's assume it is a metric space) is locally path-connected if for every open set $U$ containing $x$, there exists a  path connected open set $V$ with $x\in V\subseteq U$.

The former definition gives the sense that the neighborhood $U$ and the subneighborhood $V$ are open balls around $p$ (i.e. they are equally distributed around $p$), but the latter definition doesn't. How do I show that both the definitions are equivalent?

Comment: I don't see the difference between the definitions. Both definitions give an open path-connected subneighborhood around each open neighborhood of $p$ (or $x$).

Comment: How does the first definition imply the second? The second implies the first clearly. Am I getting the definition of a (open) neighborhood wrong here?

Comment: An open set is an open neighborhood if it contains the point you want.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification! It was a bit confusing, since even the Wikipedia page for Neighborhood defined a neighborhood of a point in a metric space as an open ball around that point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#In_a_metric_space)

Comment: To add to your confusion, Wikipedia actually defined the neighborhood of a point of a metric space to be a set containing an open ball. These discrepancies in definition are historic in nature, but they mean the same thing.